# Nuget package source setup

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I created a new solution and disabled nuget.org as my package source. I have different repositories added and all my packages are installed from there. On the build server I got an error:

> Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
>   An error occurred while sending.
>   the request. Unable to connect to the remote server.
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time

It is because my company blocked Nuget, BUT I should not have any package from that repo.

Does somebody know where I can check if my package is from nuget.org (maybe I made mistake and download from the wrong source) or where to disable in solution/ NuGet that source permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nuget package source setup

Since you are disable `nuget.org` as package source for your solution, so you should also disable it by the `disabledPackageSources` on the build server:

Go to the folder on your build server `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`, add following to that file:

```
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
```

Besides, if you are using TFS/VSTS to restore the nuget package, you can disable it from definition:

[image]